# Es6 map array with html doesn't work in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a const in render function like const `arr = ["james","john"];`

and in the return function I do

```
<select>
    arr.map(item =>
    <option>item</option>
    )
</select>
```

What I see in the output is item, not the value of the array. Am I missing something? I want to populate the array value as options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Content inside JSX elements will normally be interpreted as "text", so React treats `arr.map(…)` as the literal content of the `<select>` element.

(`<option>item</option>` is therefore simply treated as the literal child element of `<select>`; your browser probably ignores the surrouding text, which is why you only see "item" in your list).

When you instead want it to be treated as a JavaScript expression, simply wrap it in curly brackets (as explain in the "[Introducing JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)" page of React's quick start guide):

```
<select>
  {arr.map(item =>
    <option>{item}</option>
  )}
</select>
```

Comment: Now I got 3 "item". I think you missed the curly bracket on the item.

Comment: @JessicaRobertson You're right, I've updated so it should be correct now.